# Adding classes in c++?

Tags: c++, class, sum, cout, cin

I'm reading a C++ book (I've programmed in C before), it's called C++ Primer 5th edition.
I found it on a post with all stackoverflow's recommended books.
When we start learning classes, it shows something like this (not exactly):

```
Class1 c1, c2;
cin >> c1 >> c2;
if(c1.getName() == c2.getName()){
    cout << c1 + c2 << endl;
}
```

Does this make sense? What's in the classes doesn't matter I just want to know if there is any class where that would be possible and if there is could you give me an example?
Imagine if each class had a name and a number (string getName(), int getNumber()), when you use cin what would happen? And when you use cout of c1? What does c1+c2 mean?
Thanks, I hope you can help me!

Edit: Oh and btw, in Java we use c1.getName().equals(c2.getName()) to compare strings, is that needed in C++?

Comment: [Operator overloading](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html)

Comment: You should probably read further into the book - you are getting ahead of yourself a bit. It will almost certainly explain what this means later on.

Comment: You don't need equals in C++, just ==, unlike Java and C#

Comment: Thank you guys. You're right Caribou, I understand that now haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this make sense?

It could.

> What's in the classes doesn't matter I just want to know if there is any class where that would be possible and if there is could you give me an example? Imagine if each class had a name and a number (string getName(), int getNumber()), when you use cin what would happen?

The code assumes `>>` is defined to get values for the fields, such as could be done with...

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Class1& x)
{
    return is >> x.name_ >> x.number_;
}
```

Sadly, the code doesn't check if the conversion succeeds (i.e. the input can be parsed into strings and numbers as hoped.  Better code would be:

```
Class1 c1, c2;
if (cin >> c1 >> c2)
    if(c1.getName() == c2.getName())
        cout << c1 + c2 << endl;
```

Say you type "hello 20 goodbye 30" -> you'd end up with `c1`'s fields set to "hello" and 20 respectively, and obvious `c2` set to "goodbye" and 30.

> And when you use cout of c1?

If you stream `c1`, the output is determined by the operator you create.  A simple implementation would be:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Class1& c)
{
    return os << c.name_ << ' ' << c.number_;
}
```

> What does c1+c2 mean? Thanks, I hope you can help me!

This means whatever a matching function tells it to mean, for example - you might like:

```
Class1 operator+(const Class1& lhs, const Class1& rhs)
{
    return Class1(lhs.name_ + rhs.name_, lhs.number_ + rhs.number_);
}
```

Or, you might want to concatenate digits so `number_` 7 and 23 make 723... whatever makes sense in the context of your program.

> Edit: Oh and btw, in Java we use c1.getName().equals(c2.getName()) to compare strings, is that needed in C++?

Normally we create a comparison function so we can use `==`:

```
bool operator==(const Class1& lhs, const Class1& rhs)
{
    return lhs.name_ == rhs.name_ && lhs.number_ == rhs.number_;
}
```

Of course, you can do things like ignore case differences, consider "Anthony" and "Tony" to be equivalent etc..

Comment: Thanks for the very clear answer! I couldn't do that myself at this level, but at least I understand it and that's all I wanted right now.
I think you didn't understand my last question but it's okay, someone else answered it.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking is nothing but operator overloading. `c1 and c2` are objects of `Class1`. Here `Extraction operator(>>) and + operator` has been overloaded.

Check this out:-

[Operator Overloading in C++](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_overloading.html)

Example of a class overloading >> and << operator:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Distance
{
   private:
      int feet;             // 0 to infinite
      int inches;           // 0 to 12
   public:
      // required constructors
      Distance(){
         feet = 0;
         inches = 0;
      }
      Distance(int f, int i){
         feet = f;
         inches = i;
      }
      friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, 
                                       const Distance &D )
      { 
         output << "F : " << D.feet << " I : " << D.inches;
         return output;            
      }

      friend istream &operator>>( istream  &input, Distance &D )
      { 
         input >> D.feet >> D.inches;
         return input;            
      }
};
int main()
{
   Distance D1(11, 10), D2(5, 11), D3;

   cout << "Enter the value of object : " << endl;
   cin >> D3;
   cout << "First Distance : " << D1 << endl;
   cout << "Second Distance :" << D2 << endl;
   cout << "Third Distance :" << D3 << endl;


   return 0;
}
```

Source:- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/input_output_operators_overloading.htm

Comment: Thank you. I would give you a "useful answer" if I could lol...
Whoever wrote that example is a perv, I mean... D.inches... really?
Jk hehe